# input must be empty or a format string

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, fuzzy

Hi I keep getting an error with this:

```
%% generate sample data
K = 3;
numObservarations = 12000;
dimensions = 20;
data = fopen('M.dat','rt');
C = textscan(data,[numObservarations dimensions]);
```

??? Error using ==> textscan
Second input must be empty or a format string.

I tryed this method:

```
%% format data
%# read the list of features
fid = fopen('kddcup.names','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s', 'Delimiter',':', 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);

%# determine type of features
C{2} = regexprep(C{2}, '.$','');              %# remove "." at the end
attribNom = [ismember(C{2},'symbolic');true]; %# nominal features

%# build format string used to read/parse the actual data
frmt = cell(1,numel(C{1}));
frmt( ismember(C{2},'continuous') ) = {'%f'}; %# numeric features: read as number
frmt( ismember(C{2},'symbolic') ) = {'%s'};   %# nominal features: read as string
frmt = [frmt{:}];
frmt = [frmt '%s'];                           %# add the class attribute

%# read dataset
fid = fopen('kddcup.data_10_percent_corrected','rt');
C = textscan(fid, frmt, 'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);

%# convert nominal attributes to numeric
ind = find(attribNom);
G = cell(numel(ind),1);
for i=1:numel(ind)
    [C{ind(i)},G{i}] = grp2idx( C{ind(i)} );
end

%# all numeric dataset
M = cell2mat(C);
data = M;

%% generate sample data
K = 3;
numObservarations = 12000;
dimensions = 20;
data = textscan([numObservarations dimensions]);

%% cluster
opts = statset('MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);

%% plot data+clusters
figure, hold on
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 50, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 200, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')

%% plot clusters quality
figure
[silh,h] = silhouette(data, clustIDX);
avrgScore = mean(silh);
%% Assign data to clusters
% calculate distance (squared) of all instances to each cluster centroid
D = zeros(numObservarations, K);     % init distances
for k=1:K
%d = sum((x-y).^2).^0.5
D(:,k) = sum( ((data - repmat(clusters(k,:),numObservarations,1)).^2), 2);
end

% find  for all instances the cluster closet to it
[minDists, clusterIndices] = min(D, [], 2);
% compare it with what you expect it to be
sum(clusterIndices == clustIDX)
```

but get the error:

```
??? Error using ==> textscan
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to
generate a valid file identifier.

Error in ==> kmeans at 37
data = textscan([numObservarations
dimensions]);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for *textscan*? It tells you that the second input must be a string of conversion specifiers. Just look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: i will post the full code i have

Comment: Your first two uses of `textscan` are okay - you just need to model the third one after them... or did you get the beginning of your code from somewhere/someone else?

Comment: Hey jonas yes im just trying to learn how matlab works and how clustering works, the method is from previous questions and stacks own history on k-means. Just not sure how to combine the two methods yet.

Comment: I see that you have tried to merged code from these [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712748/fcm-clustering-numeric-data-and-csv-excel-file/7721674#7721674) [solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373516/matlabk-means-clustering/1400760#1400760), but why did you replace RAND with TEXTSCAN? That part was supposed to generate sample data, which in your case is really not necessary, as you have read actual data from file...

Comment: hi amro thats what i was trying to work out? I couldnt read the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call of `textscan` is not compliant with the syntax required. The following signatures are valid:

```
C = textscan(fid, 'format')
C = textscan(fid, 'format', N)
C = textscan(fid, 'format', 'param', value)
C = textscan(fid, 'format', N, 'param', value)
C = textscan(str, ...)
[C, position] = textscan(...)
```